# Weak * topology on a finite-dimensional simplex

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology

I'm trying to endow a set of probability measures $\triangle\left(X\right)
 $  with the weak * topology, where $X=\left\{ x_{1},\, x_{2},\,...,\, x_{N}\right\} \subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a finite set of elements. Of course, this seems very straightforward because the set of probability measures can be identified with the n-dimensional simplex

$\hspace{5cm} S^{N}=\left\{ p\in\mathbb{R}^{N}\,|\, p\geq0,\,\underset{i}{\sum}p_{i}=1\right\}$

My question is this identification. Is it "natural" to identify $\triangle\left(X\right)
 $ with $S^{N}$ (that is, treating each $p \in S^{N}$ as a probability measure defined as, for each $A \subset X$,  $p(A)=\underset{x_{i}\in A}{\sum}p_{i} $ ) and then give $S^{N}$ the topology with subbasis elements of the form

$\hspace{3cm}\left\{ p\in S^{N}\,|\,\left|\underset{i}{\sum}f\left(x_{i}\right)p_{i}-a\right|<\varepsilon\right\},$ $\hspace{1cm} f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\epsilon>0$

Thanks for your help. I know it's kind of a weird question I just want to make sure I'm staying consistent with definitions.